# How can I get Bluemix to pull in multiple runtimes?

Tags: deployment, runtime, ibm-cloud

My primary application requires the node.js runtime on Bluemix. However, other components of my application require both Python and Java. How can get Bluemix to pull in all 3 runtimes when I push my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend following the microservices architecture and keeping the deployment lifecyle of each of your three applications separate. You can have a manifest.yml file for each of your application and push that application when it needs to be updated. This allows you to scale them individually as well.

If you really need to push and update all 3 applications at the same time, you can write a simple script that does a cf push with each manifest.

```
cf push -f ./some_directory/application1/
cf push -f ./some_directory/application2/
cf push -f ./some_directory/application3/
```

You can also have multiple applications defined in ONE manifest file
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#multi-apps

```
---
# this manifest deploys two applications
# apps are in flame and spark directories
# flame and spark are in fireplace
# cf push should be run from fireplace
applications:
- name: spark
  memory: 1G
  instances: 2
  host: flint-99
  domain: shared-domain.com
  path: ./spark/
  services:
  - mysql-flint-99
- name: flame
  memory: 1G
  instances: 2
  host: burnin-77
  domain: shared-domain.com
  path: ./flame/
  services:
  - redis-burnin-77
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need three different runtimes, there's a good chance you have multiple components in your application (in this case, node, python, and java components). It will likely be easier for you to maintain and debug if you break your application into a number of smaller applications that use REST to pass data back and forth. This requires some additional work, but the benefit is probably worth it.

If you're certain you need multiple buildpacks, you might be able to use  [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi?cm_mc_uid=67466847845814472525610&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1454686706) from GitHub to pull in multiple buildpacks, but this can require you to maintain unstable configurations that will likely cause issues in the long run. Nonetheless, it can be done if you create `.buildpacks` that specifies the other buildpacks (reference by complete URLs).